# How do I fix this error in Spyder: No module named 'flask'

Tags: python, flask

##### Updated:

So after doing some digging I was able to find that if I add a **'!'** before `pip` it allows me to run pip inside of Spyder. (I was unable to run pip inside the console originally. That is why below you will see I ran a version check on `flask` in a python cmd

Here I'm trying to install the latest version of `flask` just to make sure I have it installed.

If I run `!pip install Flask` I get the following:

> Requirement already satisfied: Flask in {path}\python37-32\lib\site-packages (2.0.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=2.0 in {path}\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from Flask) (2.0.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.0 in {path}\spyder\pkgs (from Flask) (3.0.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.0 in {path}\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from Flask) (2.0.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: click>=7.1.2 in {path}\spyder\pkgs (from Flask) (8.0.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: colorama in {path}\spyder\pkgs (from click>=7.1.2->Flask) (0.4.4)
> Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0.0rc2 in {path}\spyder\pkgs (from Jinja2>=3.0->Flask) (2.0.0)

That means that `flask` is definitely installed and can be reached by Spyder. When I run the file the following command is run:

```
runfile('{path_to_folder}/{file_name}.py', wdir='{path_to_folder}')
```

I still don't know what is wrong with this, and I don't use Spyder very often so I don't believe it could be an environment variable that I messed with causing the issue.

---

##### Original Post:

So the issue is when I run my code in spyder I get the error below

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

I'm importing flask at the top of my program. Below is what I get when I run my .py file in spyder.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
```

I checked to make sure I have flask installed and I do. I ran python in cmd to check which version of flask I was runnning.

```
>>> import flask
>>> flask.__version__
'2.0.1'
```

I'm not sure what else could be the issue. I'm not using a virtual environment so that isn't causing an issue.

Comment: How did you invoke Python in the two examples, respectively?

Comment: I use Flask to create a web app, and I use jsonify to turn my http responses into json.

Comment: That doesn't answer what you did to start the Python interpreter. What I'm after is: what did you do differently so that `import flask` fails in the first example, but succeeds in the second example?

Comment: Ah, I understand. The first example is what I get when I run the .py file in spyder. The second example is when I run python in cmd.

Comment: seems like mismatch of interpreters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Problem

---

Here was the issue.

From what I can tell it's related to a known issue in Spyder 5. When I started the project that I'm currently working on I updated to the latest version of Spyder. Apparently, there is an issue with some of the dependences in Spyder 5 and that was causing the issue.

You can read more about the exact issue [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/15091)

##### Solution

---

I simply downgraded to Spyder 4 until the patch for this issue is released.